# Convergence of Optimization Algorithms on Non-Convex Functions

Tags: functions, optimization

Have any major results been established on the use of gradient descent for optimizing non-convex and noisy functions?

It seems like the majority of the desirable properties of gradient based optimization algorithms are intended for convex and well defined functions.

But does anyone know if these same gradient based optimization functions make any claims about their performance on non-convex and noisy functions (e.g. when we only have discrete realizations available from the target function)?

I found a reference here http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6787/2017fa/Lecture7.pdf (page 34) which seems to indicate that in theory, gradient descent can be used on non-convex functions - but I can't really find anything clear-cut online.

Does anyone know if any convergence results have been established surrounding gradient descent on non-convex functions? Or is this still open territory?

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there is no structure on the function then it is hopeless. If you want to still have nice convergence properties but without convexity, there are results under various different assumptions on the function. The paper "Linear Convergence of Gradient and Proximal-Gradient Methods Under the Polyak- Lojasiewicz Condition"(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04636.pdf) gives an overview on some of the weaker conditions that people have considered. Use this as a starting point of your investigation to find what results are most appropriate to the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Can you please clarify what you mean by "If there is no structure on the function then it is hopeless" ? What do you mean by "structure"? do you mean "if you only have discrete points from the function" instead of the actual equation? thanks!

Comment: What I mean by structure is that the function $f$ you are optimizing on has some property (i.e., convex, PL condition, etc.). If you want to prove convergence (to the global minimum) for any function then it is very easy to construct functions that gradient will fail. ("Many local minimum" examples on https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/optimization.html). Also without some property on the function $f$ the minimum might not even exist, e.g., f(x) = x. You need to have some property on $f$ to say anything meaningful about gradient descent.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant “gradient-based” more than “gradient-descent”. Gradient based methods will work in most cases (except discontinuous and weird functions) to give you a *local* minimum. There is no guarantee and no way that they will reach towards a global optimum. That’s why global optimization algorithms have been developed, and even those can easily struggle to give you (probably) a global optimum.

I am not exactly sure I understand your question. Gradient *descent* as a technique per se has piss poor performances on anything that is not smooth and convex and nice. But then again, there is no glory in minimizing a convex function, any algorithm will do.

If you’re looking at gradient descent on discontinuous/discrete objective functions then you’re out of luck.

Comment: “There is no glory in minimizing a convex function, any algorithm will do “  Decades of brilliant work have gone into developing interior point methods, proximal algorithms, etc, in order to solve convex optimization problems efficiently. It is a rich subject with a long history.

Comment: This is only true if you’re looking at constrained optimization problems. Bound-constrained or unconstrained convex functions require no special algorithm. The OP does not specify what type of problems they are referring to.

Comment: Even for smooth unconstrained convex problems, we have quasi-Newton methods, accelerated gradient methods (Nesterov acceleration, etc), and more. We can do way better than gradient descent.

Comment: Agreed, that’s also why I said gradient descent has piss poor performances. My point was related to convex, bound constrained problems. We do have a multitude of methods but convex functions pose little issues. One of the reasons why there’s so many algorithms that can work on those problems is that they’re by far the easiest to tackle.